# Oracle update using random map

Tags: sql, oracle, random

I have a need to update records in a table changing the order of the rows randomly similar to shuffling a deck of cards. The records have Id, Name, and Ordinal fields where Ordinal is initially set to the same value as Id.  I need to randomize the order of a range of records and not all records in the table. Ordinal needs to be unique at the end of the update.

Initial records:

```
Id  Name      Ordinal
--- --------- -------
  1 Item 1          1
  2 Item 2          2
  3 Item 3          3
  4 Item 4          4
  5 Item 5          5
  6 Item 6          6
```

What I want after update:

```
Id  Name      Ordinal
--- --------- -------
  1 Item 1          5
  2 Item 2          2
  3 Item 3          4
  4 Item 4          1
  5 Item 5          6
  6 Item 6          3
```

I've tried the following (simplified to use only the first 50 records). The core of the inner select does return a good map of values, but I'm seeing duplicate and skipped values in the results (notice 2 5's and no 2's):

```
UPDATE cards 
SET Ordinal = (SELECT ordinal_to 
  FROM (SELECT ROWNUM as ordinal_from, r as ordinal_to 
    FROM (SELECT ROWNUM r, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE as rv 
      FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 50 ORDER BY rv)
  ) WHERE ordinal_from = cards.Ordinal
) WHERE cards.Id BETWEEN 1 and 50;
```

What I'm getting after update:

```
Id  Name      Ordinal
--- --------- -------
  1 Item 1          5
  2 Item 2          3
  3 Item 3          4
  4 Item 4          1
  5 Item 5          6
  6 Item 6          5
```

Apparently the ordinal_from/ordinal_to values are being calculated and randomized for each updated record instead of once at the beginning of the update.

I know I could create a temporary table to hold the mapping values and use it for the update, but I'd rather avoid a temporary table.

Is there any way to do this in a single SQL command that doesn't use a temporary table?

Comment: Have you tried looping through the data set one by one, creating a random number for each record as you go, and then excluding that number from being used again as you progress in the loop?

Comment: @DanielMarcus - Even if that is possible (no doubt it is), it's absolutely the wrong way to solve such problems. Everything should be done in a single SQL statement, operating on the entire data set at once. "Do things one by one" is a mark of exceptionally poor SQL knowledge and practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this. You don't need a temporary table. The `merge` statement is often better than a straight `update` when you update values in one table based on values (stored or calculated) from another table - even if it is **the same** table.

Full example (including the creation of the table):

```
create table cards as
  select 1 as id, 'Item 1' as name, 1 as ordinal from dual union all
  select 2      , 'Item 2'        , 2 as ordinal from dual union all
  select 3      , 'Item 3'        , 3 as ordinal from dual union all
  select 4      , 'Item 4'        , 4 as ordinal from dual union all
  select 5      , 'Item 5'        , 5 as ordinal from dual union all
  select 6      , 'Item 6'        , 6 as ordinal from dual
;

merge into cards s
  using ( select rowid as rid,
                 row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value()) as rn
          from   cards
        ) t
    on (s.rowid = t.rid)
when matched then update set s.ordinal = t.rn
;

select * from cards;

        ID NAME      ORDINAL
---------- ------ ----------
         1 Item 1          3
         2 Item 2          6
         3 Item 3          4
         4 Item 4          5
         5 Item 5          2
         6 Item 6          1
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks for the advice.  In my case, I need to put a where clause in the using select statement to select only a certain block of records.

Comment: @LeeGreco - you should be able to adapt (in any case, this is the right way, or one of the right ways, to solve this kind of problems). Feel free to follow up if you need more help.